# How detect user facebook is blocked with javascript or PHP, ¿sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

How can I know if a user list was blocked by me?
by javascript or php

suppose I have a list of 10 user ...

// array of FB_ID (facebook user ID)

I can think of this ...

```
user_list = [6546f4646464,46546465465,6546487498798,4321316315,
65474657687,134112121,312125477];


$.getJSON ('https://graph.facebook.com/feed?callback=xxx&FBID=user_list[0]?')
.success (function (yy) {

// do something if facebook is available

console.log (yy);

if (yy) {

// user exists

} else {

// user blocked

}

});
```

Comment: i don´t think there is any way to do that. how did you even get the ids? you´re not supposed to get (or use) any ids of users who did not specifically authorize your app. but since there is no access token in your api call, you are most likely not even using an app.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this via API.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an application Facebook, I am a common user FB, I have 200 friends for example, 2 months ago I was able to get their FB_ID, seeing my panel of friends with HTML.

```
all_friends = [13211,3123213,123131 ... other 197 friends];
```

I want to verify if my friends are blocked ...